# how can i fit all child inside the parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I style the CSS so the 'out of stock' button stays inside the box and the product description can be fit according to the button and overflowing text can be scrolled?

```css
.productView {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.productView .product {
  padding: 0.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  border-radius: 13px;
  min-width: 800px;
}

.productView .product img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 13px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.productView .product .cross {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #444;
}

.productView .product span {
  align-self: center;
}

.productView .product .pname {
  font-size: 3vh;
}

.productView .product .pdesc {
  font-size: 2.1vh;
  margin: -5px 4px -10px 6px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .productView .product {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 60%;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    min-width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-height: 70%;
    height: fit-content;
  }
  .productView .product img {
    max-width: 80%;
  }
  .productView .product .pname {
    font-size: 2.75vh;
  }
  .productView .product .pdesc {
    font-size: 2vh;
    margin: -5px 4px -5px 4px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="productView" style="display: flex;">
  <div class="product">
    <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x cross"></i>
    <img src="../img/crossiant.webp">
    <span>
      <div class="tag">
        <h6>Out Of Stock</h6>
      </div>
      <h3 class="pname">
        Crossiant (2pcs)
        <i class="fa fa-heart-o heart"></i>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="pdesc">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer 
        took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
      </h3>
      <h4 class="price-view" align="center">
        <span>₹0</span>
        <span class="price-cut-view">
          <s></s>
        </span>
      </h4>
      <p>
        <a class="cart_btn oos">Out Of Stock</a>
      </p>
    </span>
  </div>
</div
```

It looks like this on mobile devices:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is from either the screenshot or code example - where ***should*** the button appear? Also note that your HTML is invalid - you can't put block-level elements (eg. `div`, `h3`, `h4`, `p`) inside an inline element (eg. `span`)

Answer (score -1):

first of all your html is invalid like @Rory McCrossan said you cant put block elements inside in-line elements. I highly suggest you fix it.

now about your problem you want everything to fit. for that i have added
two properties to you `pdesc`

`white-space: pre;` meaning Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will only wrap on line breaks. you can also try other white-space properties for you liking e.g:`white-space:no-wrap;` it makes the text appear only in one line.

`overflow:auto;` why overflow auto? you ask why not `scroll` .if we set it to scroll it will automatically add both scroll bar horizontal and vertical even if we only needed horizontal scroll bar like in this example.
as for `auto`:The auto value is similar to scroll, but it adds scrollbars only when necessary.
i also added a scroll bar properties to make the scroll bar look good but thats
not necessary.hope you fix your `HTML`.

```css
.productView {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.productView .product {
  padding: 0.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  border-radius: 13px;
  min-width: 800px;
}

.productView .product img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 13px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.productView .product .cross {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #444;
}

.productView .product span {
  align-self: center;
}

.productView .product .pname {
  font-size: 3vh;
}

.productView .product .pdesc {
  font-size: 2.1vh;
  margin: -5px 4px -10px 6px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .productView .product {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 60%;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    min-width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-height: 70%;
    height: fit-content;
  }
  .productView .product img {
    max-width: 80%;
  }
  .productView .product .pname {
    font-size: 2.75vh;
  }
  .productView .product .pdesc {
    font-size: 2vh;
    white-space: pre;
    overflow:auto;
    margin: -5px 4px -5px 4px;
  }
  .pdesc::-webkit-scrollbar{
   width: 5px;
   height: 8px;
   background-color: #aaa;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="productView" style="display: flex;">
  <div class="product">
    <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x cross"></i>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558909552-8fcf7c94b575?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80">
    <span>
      <div class="tag">
        <h6>Out Of Stock</h6>
      </div>
      <h3 class="pname">
        Crossiant (2pcs)
        <i class="fa fa-heart-o heart"></i>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="pdesc">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer 
        took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
      </h3>
      <h4 class="price-view" align="center">
        <span>₹0</span>
        <span class="price-cut-view">
          <s></s>
        </span>
      </h4>
      <p>
        <a class="cart_btn oos">Out Of Stock</a>
      </p>
    </span>
  </div>
</div
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. I have been trying to solve this issue for days. Can you also help me with the block element inside inline element? What should i use instead of the block element?

Comment: i think you misunderstood.block elements should not be inside the in-line elements.but in-line elements can be inside block elements.
so you have to think.if you are like making a container which will have other elements inside it. making sure you dont choose in-line elements as the parent.it should be block element.& yes you can also put block element inside another block element. 
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you need to fit-content in the height of the parent